# How do I write the ARMHF OMAP4 image to an sdcard?

Tags: arm

I'm trying to write Ubuntu_12.04_armhf_Omap4 image on a SD card for the first time.

After decompressing the image I get a raw file.
Does it need to be converted to .img file, or what else?

Answer (score 0):

Installation instruction is here

For ubuntu 12.04 desktop image → https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/OmapDesktopInstall

For others and old versions → https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/OMAP